# Use multiple checkbox selection while parsing JSON

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to select multiple checkboxes in a custom listview while parsing JSON. Now I am able select a single checkbox. How can I select multiple checkbox values?

Comment: Use class selector, can you? No, what did you try?

Comment: Could you show us a bit of your code? And, I think you mean "multiple checkboxes", not "multiple checkbox values"? A checkbox should have only one value.